# EC2 unhealthy instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

ELB show that my instance is available in the appropriate zone but unhealthy. I'm tried to make request from this instance to his own health-check endpoint but received 503.

curl -I public-IP:port/target-healthy-endpoint

```
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
Date: Thu, 04 Aug 2016 17:25:10 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

What does it mean, and where should I look? On aws doc found only this:

```
Solution 3: Ensure that you have healthy instances in every Availability Zone that your load balancer is configured to respond in. Verify this by looking at the HealthyHostCount in CloudWatch.
```

Comment: Well, you need to check if your service is running on that instance.

Comment: Which public IP are you using to test in your `curl` command? The IP of the EC2 instance or the IP of the ELB load balancer?

Comment: How have you set the ELB health check? Check this screenshot http://imgur.com/a/8PGau can you provide yours?

Comment: @MattHouser ip of ec2

Comment: @error2007s  http://imgur.com/a/JlPx4

Comment: The health check does not have to directly reference a file. It can be any valid URL that returns a 200 status code. If `/health/test` returns a 200 status code, then it's a valid health check.

Answer (score 1):

If you are indeed pinging the public IP address of your EC2 instance, and `curl`ing your health check URL is returning a 503 error code, then stop thinking of this as an ELB issue. You won't find the solution in the AWS docs.

The pure fact is that your EC2 instance is responding 503 on it's own accord. Sign-in to your EC2 instance and fix that problem until it responds with a 200 status code using `curl`. It may be a configuration issue with your http server (IIS, Apache, other).

As an aside, since your EC2 instance is fronted by ELB, the EC2 instance should reside in a private subnet rather than a public subnet. It won't make your setup functionally better, but it will hide what doesn't need to be public.